# Create a model using SVM in R

Tags: r, svm

I need some help with creating SVM models and ROC curve in R. I got several errors:Error in levels(data[, "pred"]) : argument "data" is missing, with no default. Error: Every row has at least one missing value were found. How should I fix it? Thanks in advance!! Here's the google drive link to the dataset:[data](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/my-drive)

Here's the code I tried:

```
library(caret)
library(pROC)
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                           number = 10, 
                           repeats= 10,
                           classProbs =  TRUE,
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary())            

data<-read.csv("full_train_binary.csv")

data_training<-subset(data[which(data$X==0),])
data_testing<-subset(data[which(data$X==1),])

training<-data_training
testing<-data_testing

cols_remove <- c("patient_sk","New_admitted_dt_tm", "New_discharge_dt_tm")

training<-training[,!(colnames(training)%in%cols_remove)]
testing<-testing[,!(colnames(testing)%in%cols_remove)]

set.seed(825)

start.time <- Sys.time()

svm_one <- train(death~., data = training, 
                 method = 'svmRadial',                   
                 trControl = fitControl, 
                 verbose = FALSE,
                 tunelength=5,
                 metric="ROC")
svm_one

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken


svm_one_pred <- predict(svm_one, newdata=testing,type = 'prob')
roc_svm_one <- roc(testing$death, as.vector(svm_one_pred[,1]))
pROC::auc(roc_svm_one)
```

Result:

```
> library(caret)
> library(pROC)
> fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
+                            number = 10, 
+                            repeats= 10,
+                            classProbs =  TRUE,
+                            summaryFunction = twoClassSummary())            
Error in levels(data[, "pred"]) : 
  argument "data" is missing, with no default
> 
> data<-read.csv("full_train_binary.csv")
> 
> data_training<-subset(data[which(data$X==0),])
> data_testing<-subset(data[which(data$X==1),])
> 
> training<-data_training
> testing<-data_testing
> 
> cols_remove <- c("patient_sk","New_admitted_dt_tm", "New_discharge_dt_tm")
> 
> training<-training[,!(colnames(training)%in%cols_remove)]
> testing<-testing[,!(colnames(testing)%in%cols_remove)]
> 
> set.seed(825)
> 
> start.time <- Sys.time()
> 
> svm_one <- train(death~., data = training, 
+                  method = 'svmRadial',                      
+                  trControl = fitControl, 
+                  verbose = FALSE,
+                  tunelength=5,
+                  metric="ROC")
Error: Every row has at least one missing value were found
> svm_one
Support Vector Machines with Radial Basis Function Kernel 

4911 samples
1954 predictors
   2 classes: 'False', 'True' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 3928, 3928, 3929, 3930, 3929 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  sigma         C          Accuracy   Kappa        
  1.976927e-05  192.56972  0.7448586  -0.0004065338
  2.778991e-05  242.26352  0.7446545   0.0007460142
  3.273858e-05   14.39494  0.7450623   0.0000000000

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final values used for the model were sigma = 3.273858e-05 and C
 = 14.39494.
> 
> end.time <- Sys.time()
> time.taken <- end.time - start.time
> time.taken
Time difference of 0.395869 secs
> 
> 
> svm_one_pred <- predict(svm_one, newdata=testing,type = 'prob')
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'patient_sk' not found
> roc_svm_one <- roc(testing$death, as.vector(svm_one_pred[,1]))
Error in as.vector(svm_one_pred[, 1]) : object 'svm_one_pred' not found
> pROC::auc(roc_svm_one)
Error in pROC::auc(roc_svm_one) : object 'roc_svm_one' not found
```

Comment: Hi @meganshyu, try not to share images, it's not useful in reproducing the error or solving your problem.. It's a huge chunk here. The first error message comes from summaryFunction = twoClassSummary(), you just write summaryFunction = twoClassSummary

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I'll delete the image.@StupidWolf

Comment: No problem. There's a few other errors and I am not sure what actually happened. If it is possible to share your data somehow we may be able to take a look

Comment: It's quite a big dataset. Here's my google drive link: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/my-drive

Comment: If i click that link i see my own google drive :) you needa share a link to the file

Comment: Sorry, it's a long day. Here's the correct one:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G10yGNtMX8b1lF4f0MR0DDcsiSo2qXqkkgf_lWFLB1s/edit?usp=sharing@StupidWolf

Comment: Yeah, cos it's too large to import all the data, so I just keeps 25 lines

Answer (score 0):

Ok I can only get 25 lines of your files and I somehow ended with 200+ columns of all zeros when I read in full_train_binary.csv.

Looking at the output above, seems like you 4000 lines, so I just put some suggestions to your code below (with comments in #) and hopefully you can run it without error:

```
library(caret)
library(pROC)
# just twoClassSummary without ()
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                            number = 10, 
                            repeats= 10,
                            classProbs =  TRUE,
                            summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)            

data<-read.csv("full_train_binary.csv")
cols_remove <- c("patient_sk","New_admitted_dt_tm", "New_discharge_dt_tm")
# remove this here

data = data[,setdiff(colnames(data),cols_remove)]
# create an index to train 70% of your data
#your previous subset(..) just doesn't make sense

idx = sample(nrow(data),round(0.7*nrow(data)))
data_training<-data[idx,]
data_testing<-data[-idx,]

svm_one <- train(death~., data = training, 
                  method = 'svmRadial',                      
                  trControl = fitControl, 
                  verbose = FALSE,
                  tunelength=5,
                  metric="ROC")

svm_one_pred <- predict(svm_one, newdata=testing,type = 'prob')
roc_svm_one <- roc(testing$death, as.vector(svm_one_pred[,1]))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try.